# Agreeing on a time subject to change using the world 'preliminary'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

The conversation might go something like this:

> Q: "What time would you like to meet next Friday?"
>   A: "Let's say 11am preliminary"

The person answering means to say 11am is not a firm time but may be changed before Friday.

Is this a correct usage of *preliminary*?

If not is there a word that can take its place?

Comment: [*Preliminary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preliminary) is an adjective (or a substituted noun), which would indicate that this is not a correct use.

Comment: *Preliminarily* would be correct

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your question with a ‘yes’ or ‘no’.  The word ‘usage’ is about how a word in a language is generally used by speakers of that language.

As far as I can tell, there is no instance of this usage for this word.  But it is obvious what you mean.  So *something* is right about it.

If you were a media celebrity, or influential in the world of business or politics, maybe this locution will catch on, just as the usage of ‘access’ as a transitive verb caught on in the late 20th century.

As so often, ‘the Greeks had a word for it’:  *hapax legomenon (άπαξ λεγόμενον)*, meaning *once spoken*.  It indicated that we know what this famous writer means, but, as far as we know, it is a one-off.

Now times have have changed.  ‘Correctness’ is not just a matter of what the literary/political élites write.  It has been, if you will, democratised.  For now, I should say your usage is *idiosyncratic*.  The snobbish Brit in me might call it an *americanism*.

You open up a deep question about English usage.  The status of the English language as the World language opens up a situation in which traditional native speakers are heavily outnumbered by non-native speakers.  How should linguists respond to that?  Do we put a fence around British and US speakers?  That doesn’t seem right.  But ignoring the wider world of speakers doesn’t seem right.  So the writing of dictionaries and grammars is, and always has had a political aspect.  But this is a meta issue.  For now, your sentence is non-standard but easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Some better alternatives:

- Let's **tentatively** say 11am.
- Let's **provisionally** say 11am.
- Let's **pencil in** 11am.